Type C is V .The type C not a pure alias .Why is it designed this way?
Tyep Define in the solidity docs

A user-defined value type is defined using type C is V, where C is the name of the newly introduced type and V has to be a built-in value type (the “underlying type”). The function C.wrap is used to convert from the underlying type to the custom type. Similarly, the function C.unwrap is used to convert from the custom type to the underlying type.


The type C does not have any operators or attached member functions. In particular, even the operator == is not defined. Explicit and implicit conversions to and from other types are disallowed.

Why is it designed this way?
Why don't design the keyword Type's function just as a pure alias function like the keyword Typedef's function in C++?
Just make compopiler do replace for us, they are equal.
